# Wrong data transmission I2C RasPi->Arduino

Tags: python, arduino, raspberry-pi, i2c, arduino-uno

I'm tinkering with my RaspberryPi and my Arduino to send some text over I2C. I got it working so far but there is a number appearing which shouldn't exist.

I'm sending "Hello" converting it to an int array and sending it over I2C.

```
['H','e','l','l','o'] => [72,97,108,108,111] // This should be the result
['H','e','l','l','o'] => [0, 5, 72, 101, 108, 108, 111] // This is what i get
```

The leading 0 is intentional but the 5 shouldn't exist at all!

The (shortened) code I'm running on the Arduino:

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600); // start serial for output
  // initialize i2c as slave
  Wire.begin(SLAVE_ADDRESS);

  // define callbacks for i2c communication
  Wire.onReceive(receiveData);  
  Serial.println("Ready!");
}

receiveData(int byteCount) {
    int i;

    // Iterate through the byte packets
    for(i = 0; Wire.available(); i++) { 
        number = Wire.read();

        if(i != 0) {  // Ignore the first byte
            text[i-1] = (char)number;
        }

        // Output number, byteCount, and i over the serial bus
    }

    Serial.print("Result: ");
    Serial.println(text);
}
```

The exact output I'm getting:

```
[CMD]data received: 0, 2char: , byteCount: 7, Iteration: 0 //The cmd byte
data received: 5, 2char: , byteCount: 7, Iteration: 1
data received: 72, 2char: H, byteCount: 7, Iteration: 2
data received: 101, 2char: e, byteCount: 7, Iteration: 3
data received: 108, 2char: l, byteCount: 7, Iteration: 4
data received: 108, 2char: l, byteCount: 7, Iteration: 5
data received: 111, 2char: o, byteCount: 7, Iteration: 6
Result: "Hello"
```

The code running on the RaspberryPi (Python):

```
import smbus
import time

# Initiate the SMBus on device 1
bus = smbus.SMBus(1)

# The address of the Arduino
address = 0x04

chars = [] # The character/int array
test = "Hello" # The test text

# Split up the string in individual chars, 
# convert them to int and add them to the array
for c in test:
    chars.append(ord(c))

# send the data... the 0 is the cmd byte! The function accepts an int array
bus.write_block_data(address, 0, chars)
```

Comment: what is wire ? @thetruefreestyle

Comment: don't try your own . try examples first .....

Comment: @SDilmac Oh! Sorry I forgot it in the src! Wire is the Object which handles the I2C interface on the Arduino.

Comment: @SDilmac Why not try something on your own?? I think it's too simple to just go after examples and tutorials!

Comment: read documet and related RFC's before starting your own. Example: read used ic documents for address, bus and memory mapping. otherwise lose a lot time(so quickly bored). Electronics need calculate a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just from the values shown it is likely to be the number of chars or bytes being sent in the string part of the transmission. "Hello" has 5 bytes in ASCII representation.

If you look at the description of the [smbus protocol](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/plain/Documentation/i2c/smbus-protocol) in the section for the `write_block_data` command it documents that an 8 bit Count is sent after the command byte which gives the length of the Data block.

> ### SMBus Block Write:  i2c_smbus_write_block_data()
>
> The opposite of the Block Read command, this writes up to 32 bytes to 
>   a device, to a designated register that is specified through the
>   Comm byte. The amount of data is specified in the Count byte.
>
> S Addr Wr [A] Comm [A] **Count** [A] Data [A] Data [A] ... [A] Data [A] P

Comment: Oh ^^ It seems that i missed that line while reading the documentation.